How seriously is Professor Lisa Feldman Barrett's Theory of Constructed Emotion regarded?
As a non-expert I would be interested to know professionals' opinions of Distinguished Professor Lisa Feldman Barrett's Theory of Constructed Emotion en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_constructed_emotion, popularised in her book "How Emotions Are Made: The Secret Life of the Brain" (2017), and how seriously to take her ideas.
The popularisation has some quite heavy criticisms in Amazon Ratings, mainly of her apparently assertive style of presentation, which I take to be a possible warning sign.
Informed advice would be appreciated.

In affective science there has, to date, not been a consensus on an overarching framework, with multiple frameworks coexisting in the literature (see e.g. Paul Ekman or Klaus Scherer for alternative theories). Each of these theories can cite evidence in its favour, also Feldman Barrett's work. However, given the multitude of frameworks, I would not put too much faith into any of them at this point. They are useful in guiding (and supporting) work, but are unlikely to reflect the entire and absolute "truth" at this moment; it's more likely that each of these frameworks have some aspects of truth to them whilst also (inadvertently) misrepresenting other bits ... When reading popular science, it is important to pay attention to where the author refers to an actual body of evidence and where they might be speculating. Good writers of popular science should make this distinction crystal clear! Keeping this in mind, along with the fact that her viewpoint is just one of many, might help you when reading her work.

Thank you, @Tiberius - wise counsel.
